# Where can I find documentation of Google Analytics SDK classes?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced) I've added GA to my app and it works just fine. To send hits, I use the following code:

```
getGaTracker().set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Screen Name");
getGaTracker().send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
```

But what if I want to set more parameters to this Tracker? If you check Fields.class, you will se lots of parameters that can be set.. like in `hitParameters.put(Fields.HIT_TYPE, "appview");`, can I set any arbitrary value for HIT_TYPE? Where will this appear in my stats, and what are the other fields for?
I also want to find out if I can add more parameters to 'getGaTracker().set()', in a way to add more logging levels like when [logging Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/events)...

Again from the DevGuide we have this snippet:

```
Tracker t1 = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-XXXX-1");
// Trackers may be named. By default, name is set to the property ID.
Tracker t2 = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("altTracker", "UA-XXXX-2";)
```

So the Property ID isn't the only possible parameter for instantiating a Tracker. It would be great to have some docs do check all uses for it.

The only thing I found so far is [this page](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/analytics/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/analytics/package-summary.html)

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/package-summary.html